# Why CGAffineTransformMakeRotation stretch my view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have three views, and for example A view, B view, and C view.
Let A view be the root view. I insert B view above A view, and insert C view above B view.
Now, I use  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation function to rotate my C view some degrees. But it's weird. Besides C view is rotated, the C view is also stretched (something changes the frame of C frame). I really hope to know the reason for this problem.
My part of codes: (for iOS 7)

```
_myMainClockHourHandView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
_myMainClockHourHandView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((hourHandRotateDegree * M_PI) / 180);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do the positioning using transforms as well now that you rotated it.

Identity
apply rotation
apply translation